# Pandas merge data frames as of certain index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, concatenation

I have two pandas data frames:

**x_axis:**

| index | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2023 |
| 2 | 02-01-2023 |
| 3 | 03-01-2023 |
| 4 | 04-01-2023 |
| 5 | 05-01-2023 |
| 6 | 06-01-2023 |
| 7 | 07-01-2023 |
| 8 | 08-01-2023 |
| 9 | 09-01-2023 |

**df:**

| index | snap_date | some_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03-01-2023 | 12 |
| 2 | 04-01-2023 | 85 |
| 3 | 05-01-2023 | 46 |
| 4 | 06-01-2023 | 74285 |
| 5 | 0 | 427 |
| 6 | 0 | 452 |

and I want to get such merge/concatination:

**desired_df:**

| index | date | index_y | snap_date | some_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2023 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 02-01-2023 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 03-01-2023 | 1 | 03-01-2023 | 12 |
| 4 | 04-01-2023 | 2 | 04-01-2023 | 85 |
| 5 | 05-01-2023 | 3 | 05-01-2023 | 46 |
| 6 | 06-01-2023 | 4 | 06-01-2023 | 74285 |
| 7 | 07-01-2023 | 5 | 0 | 427 |
| 8 | 08-01-2023 | 6 | 0 | 452 |
| 9 | 09-01-2023 |  |  |  |

Basically, I want to concatenate **df** to **x_axis** as of the first match of *date* and *snap_date*, but I don't want to join on the dates because also index_y 5 and 6 should be included in **desired_df**.
Further info:

- *snap_date* is always a subset of *date*
- Both *snap_date* and *date* are evenly spaced, sorted, unique and do not have NANs. Basically pandas date series.

Thank you already!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
# identify first date
first_date = df['snap_date'].iloc[0]
# and it's first index
first_index = next(iter(x_axis.index[x_axis['date'].eq(first_date)]))

# set the index of x_axis and join
out = x_axis.join(df.set_axis(x_axis.index[first_index:first_index+len(df)]),
                  rsuffix='_y')
```

Output:

```
   index        date  index_y   snap_date  some_data
0      1  01-01-2023      NaN         NaN        NaN
1      2  02-01-2023      NaN         NaN        NaN
2      3  03-01-2023      1.0  03-01-2023       12.0
3      4  04-01-2023      2.0  04-01-2023       85.0
4      5  05-01-2023      3.0  05-01-2023       46.0
5      6  06-01-2023      4.0  06-01-2023    74285.0
6      7  07-01-2023      5.0           0      427.0
7      8  08-01-2023      6.0           0      452.0
8      9  09-01-2023      NaN         NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

Calculate `num`, the amount to add to the index.

```
num = x_axis[x_axis['date'].eq(df['snap_date'].iloc[0])].index[0]
```

`num`

```
2
```

and join x_axis & df with rename

```
x_axis.join(df.rename(index=lambda x : x + num, columns={'index':'index_y'}))
```

output:

```
    index   date    index_y snap_date   some_data
0   1   01-01-2023  NaN     NaN         NaN
1   2   02-01-2023  NaN     NaN         NaN
2   3   03-01-2023  1.0     03-01-2023  12.0
3   4   04-01-2023  2.0     04-01-2023  85.0
4   5   05-01-2023  3.0     05-01-2023  46.0
5   6   06-01-2023  4.0     06-01-2023  74285.0
6   7   07-01-2023  5.0     0           427.0
7   8   08-01-2023  6.0     0           452.0
8   9   09-01-2023  NaN     NaN         NaN
```

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
         'date': ['01-01-2023', '02-01-2023', '03-01-2023', '04-01-2023', '05-01-2023', 
                  '06-01-2023', '07-01-2023', '08-01-2023', '09-01-2023']}

data2 = {'index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
         'snap_date': ['03-01-2023', '04-01-2023', '05-01-2023', '06-01-2023', '0', '0'], 
         'some_data': [12, 85, 46, 74285, 427, 452]}
x_axis = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```